# How can i create app package for SharePoint 2013 App Catalog by using MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, 2013, build, packaging

I know that I can create an app package in VisualStudio 2012 RC simply by right clicking on App Project and then clicking "Publish". But how I can do the same with MSBuild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works quite nice with command below

```
msbuild /t:Package <YourProjectNameHere> /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:OutputPath=<OutgoingPath>
```

Please also check this post  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/appsforsharepoint/thread/34fad52e-31fa-400f-ba94-dbfd97a7cc43

Answer (score 0):

can you check out this article and tell me what you think?
http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/08/01/how-to-build-a-sharepoint-hosted-client-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Hope it helps :)